# Are this model's arms too short, or it's a just a rigging problem?

Tags: rigging

In sitting position, the palms should be on a level with her butt, completely touching the surface she sits on, but they're not. They seem to be too short, but in Rest Position the arms seem fine and proportionate to the body (at least to me). Any advice on what could be the problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: hello are you sure that you've applied the armature scale? Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: everything seems normal but maybe share a version with the sitting version? or an animation that goes from default pose to sitting pose?

Comment: I may be wrong but everything seems normal, if you think that the arms are too short, maybe extend it a bit?

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.